# Calling Functions in an Executable from Python

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess, pyinstaller, exe

I need to create an executable with `pyinstaller` that contains many functions. How can I call these functions with arguments from Python? My current approach is to use conditionals based on optional arguments. For example (untested):

```py
#math_app.py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", "--add", type=str, help="Add integers together")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--subtract", type=str, help="Subtract integers")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.add:
    add_list = args.add.split(',')
    #add code here
elif args.subtract:
    sub_list = args.subtract.split(',')
    #subtract code here
```

Which, after being compiled with `pyinstaller` would be used like this:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p= Popen("math_app.exe --add=1,2,3 --subtract=10,5",stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE, encoding="UTF8")
command='START\n'
p.stdin.write(command)
p.stdin.flush()
response=p.stdout.read()
print(response)
```

Is this a good way to go about this or is there a better way to call functions & pass arguments with a Python .exe?

Thank you!

Comment: "Functions" aren't accessible from outside the program. They're internal organisational structures, not an outside interface. So yes, you'll need something like what you have to make your program invoke them.

Comment: The way you are doing it now is fine.

Answer (score -1):

Well,thats a job for the front end (GUI).You can spend a little time searching on the topic since you made a decision to make an executable.Since your project seems kinda small you can use a library like Tkinker(already available in python) or PyQt (for more advanced things) to make an interface so the user can provide the input/outputs/buttons and call your functions respectivelly.
If you have the time to invest this is the correct way to go and will make your app better and more usable even from a person not involved with programming.

Edit after downvote:Exe generally is created for non-engineers who wants to use a programm and typically involves an interface and is machine specific(Windows/Linux/Mac).If you plan to use your programm among engineers docker or other technologies are probably better(all these ofcourse are generalities and may not match your specific expectations/orders).